# probability of arranging books on shelf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

You have $n$ books on algebra, $k$ on probability and $l$ on calculus. The books are all different. If you place them on a shelf at random what is the probability that (a) Books on the same subject are adjacent. (b) Books on the same subject are in alphabetical order by author, but not necessarily adjacent. (c) Books on the same subject are adjacent and within each subject they are in alphabetical order

Answer:

There are $3$ types of books (algebra,probability,calculus) so there are 3! ways to arrange the type of book.
Within each topic there are $n!$ ways to arrange the algebra books $k!$ ways to arrange the probability books $l!$ ways to arrange the calculus books

So a) is it $3! * n! * k! * l!$ (Am i correct here???)

b) $3/{(n+k+l)!}$

c)So, the probability that Books on the same subject are adjacent and within each subject they are in alphabetical order is,

$3/(3!*n!*k!*l)$

Am i correct, can anyone please validate this.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) This is almost correct, minor oversight forgot to divide by by $(n+k+l)!$.

b) We need to choose the positions to be occupied by algebra. This can be done in $\binom{n+k+l}{n}$ ways. For each such choice, we can choose the locations of the probability books in $\binom{k+l}{k}$ ways. Multiply, then divide by $(n+k+l)!$.

Expressing in terms of factorials brings great cancellation. Staring at the simplified answer may suggest another approach.

(If you are comfortable with multinomial coefficients, there is a more symmetric approach.)

c) Of the $(n+k+l)!$ equally likely outcomes, only $3!$ satisfy the condition.

Comment: Yes. But (b) simplifies to $\dfrac{1}{n!k!l!}$.

Comment: Correct i too simplified it , Thanks André Nicolas

Comment: You are welcome.